# AWS CFN error "The parameter groupName cannot be used with the parameter subnet"

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I get error by using the following yaml. I have checked the code but I dont think there's any problem. My structure is planned to have a VPC with 2 public subnet and 2 private subnet. One web server instance will be placed in public subnet 2. I think the problem maybe related to instance creation, coz the error appear during the instance creation process.

```
Parameters:
  EnvironmentName:
    Description: An environment name that is prefixed to resource names
    Type: String

  KeyName:
    Description: Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instances
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
    ConstraintDescription: must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair.

  SSHLocation:
    Description: The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances
    Type: String
    MinLength: '9'
    MaxLength: '18'
    Default: 0.0.0.0/0
    AllowedPattern: "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})"
    ConstraintDescription: must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x.

  VpcCIDR:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for this VPC
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.0.0/16

  PublicSubnet1CIDR:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the public subnet in the first Availability Zone
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.0.0/24

  PublicSubnet2CIDR:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the public subnet in the second Availability Zone
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.2.0/24

  PrivateSubnet1CIDR:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the private subnet in the first Availability Zone
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.1.0/24

  PrivateSubnet2CIDR:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the private subnet in the second Availability Zone
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.3.0/24

Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref VpcCIDR
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  InternetGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

  PublicSubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Ref PublicSubnet1CIDR
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Public Subnet (AZ1)

  PublicSubnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 1, !GetAZs  '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Ref PublicSubnet2CIDR
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Public Subnet (AZ2)

  PrivateSubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs  '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Ref PrivateSubnet1CIDR
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Private Subnet (AZ1)

  PrivateSubnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 1, !GetAZs  '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Ref PrivateSubnet2CIDR
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Private Subnet (AZ2)

  NatGateway1EIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    DependsOn: InternetGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc

  NatGateway2EIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    DependsOn: InternetGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc

  NatGateway1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt NatGateway1EIP.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1

  NatGateway2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt NatGateway2EIP.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet2

  PublicRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Public Routes

  DefaultPublicRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: InternetGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway

  PublicSubnet1RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1

  PublicSubnet2RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet2


  PrivateRouteTable1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Private Routes (AZ1)

  DefaultPrivateRoute1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable1
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NatGateway1

  PrivateSubnet1RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable1
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet1

  PrivateRouteTable2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Private Routes (AZ2)

  DefaultPrivateRoute2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable2
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NatGateway2

  PrivateSubnet2RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable2
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet2

  WebServerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Enable HTTP access via port 80 and SSH access via port 22
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: '80'
        ToPort: '80'
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: '22'
        ToPort: '22'
        CidrIp: !Ref SSHLocation

  WebServerInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Metadata:
      Comment: Install a simple PHP application
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        config:
          packages:
            yum:
              httpd: []
              php: []
          groups:
            apache: {}
          users:
            "apache":
              groups:
                - "apache"
          sources:
            "/home/ec2-user/aws-cli": "https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/tarball/master"
          files:
            "/tmp/cwlogs/apacheaccess.conf":
              content: !Sub |
                [general]
                state_file= /var/awslogs/agent-state
                [/var/log/httpd/access_log]
                file = /var/log/httpd/access_log
                log_group_name = ${AWS::StackName}
                log_stream_name = {instance_id}/apache.log
                datetime_format = %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S
              mode: '000400'
              owner: apache
              group: apache
            "/var/www/html/index.php":
              content: !Sub |
                <?php
                echo '<h1>AWS CloudFormation sample PHP application for ${AWS::StackName}</h1>';
                ?>
              mode: '000644'
              owner: apache
              group: apache
            "/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf":
              content: !Sub |
                [main]
                stack=${AWS::StackId}
                region=${AWS::Region}
              mode: "000400"
              owner: "root"
              group: "root"
            "/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf":
              content: !Sub |
                [cfn-auto-reloader-hook]
                triggers=post.update
                path=Resources.WebServerHost.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init
                action=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource WebServerHost --region ${AWS::Region}
              mode: "000400"
              owner: "root"
              group: "root"
          commands:
            test:
              command: "echo \"$MAGIC\" > test.txt"
              env:
                MAGIC: "I come from the environment!"
              cwd: "~"
          services:
            sysvinit:
              httpd:
                enabled: 'true'
                ensureRunning: 'true'
              sendmail:
                enabled: 'false'
                ensureRunning: 'false'
    CreationPolicy:
      ResourceSignal:
        Timeout: PT5M
    Properties:
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      KeyName:
        Ref: KeyName
      ImageId: ami-a4c7edb2
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet2
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref WebServerSecurityGroup
      UserData:
        "Fn::Base64":
          !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash -xe
            # Get the latest CloudFormation package
            yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
            # Start cfn-init
            /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -s ${AWS::StackId} -r WebServerHost --region ${AWS::Region} || error_exit 'Failed to run cfn-init'
            # Start up the cfn-hup daemon to listen for changes to the EC2 instance metadata
            /opt/aws/bin/cfn-hup || error_exit 'Failed to start cfn-hup'
            # All done so signal success
            /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackId} --resource WebServerHost --region ${AWS::Region}

Outputs:
  VPC:
    Description: A reference to the created VPC
    Value: !Ref VPC

  PublicSubnets:
    Description: A list of the public subnets
    Value: !Join [ ",", [ !Ref PublicSubnet1, !Ref PublicSubnet2 ]]

  PrivateSubnets:
    Description: A list of the private subnets
    Value: !Join [ ",", [ !Ref PrivateSubnet1, !Ref PrivateSubnet2 ]]

  PublicSubnet1:
    Description: A reference to the public subnet in the 1st Availability Zone
    Value: !Ref PublicSubnet1

  PublicSubnet2:
    Description: A reference to the public subnet in the 2nd Availability Zone
    Value: !Ref PublicSubnet2

  PrivateSubnet1:
    Description: A reference to the private subnet in the 1st Availability Zone
    Value: !Ref PrivateSubnet1

  PrivateSubnet2:
    Description: A reference to the private subnet in the 2nd Availability Zone
    Value: !Ref PrivateSubnet2
```

Comment: The instance properties:
    SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref WebServerSecurityGroup

i have changed to :
   SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref WebServerSecurityGroup.

but it's still shown the same error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[SecurityGroups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-securitygroups) is only for default VPC or EC2-classic:

> For a nondefault VPC, you **must use security group IDs** instead.

Thus its better to use [SecurityGroupIds](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-securitygroups).

```
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !GetAtt WebServerSecurityGroup.GroupId
```

Also your `WebServerSecurityGroup` belongs to default VPC, but your instance is in a custom VPC. You need [VpcId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html#cfn-ec2-securitygroup-vpcid) for your security group:

```
  WebServerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Enable HTTP access via port 80 and SSH access via port 22
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: '80'
        ToPort: '80'
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: '22'
        ToPort: '22'
        CidrIp: !Ref SSHLocation
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
```

Your `cfn-signal` should be (wrong `--resource`):

```
/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackId} --resource WebServerInstance --region ${AWS::Region}
```

Comment: great answer! You helped me to solve another problem i am facing haha (cfn-signal)

Comment: @YukChan No problem. Glad I could help.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, but when I try to replace set the SecurityGroupIds value, I get this error when I try to run the script (the script launches instances via a Launch Template): 
"An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource WebServerSecurityGroup"
I guess this is due to both being defined in the same script. How do I work around this?

Answer (score 2):

When you specify the SubnetId for an instance, you should use the Security Group ID instead of the Security Group Name. Just replace `SecurityGroups` by `SecurityGroupIds` in the EC2 instance section.

Reference: [Reference1](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2453#issuecomment-281840723) [Reference2](https://acloud.guru/forums/intro-aws-cloudformation/discussion/-LKQzttlrIVPu2Zvvm1E/error-the-parameter-groupname-cannot-be-used-with-the-parameter-subnet?answer=-LQnurDjbs9kUnL-CCnr)